# What's an effective way of comparing orderings?

Tags: permutations

Given two orderings of some set of things, what's an effective way to quantify how similar the orderings are?

For instance, say I have the orderings

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
```

If I just use the number of elements in the right positions, I get that the two orderings are not similar at all, which I don't think is true. There must be a better way to quantify their similarity.

My intuition is that this ordering should take into account how many elements are displaced as well as how far the displacements are.

Comment: How about the [1][Mann-Whitney $U$-test]?: [1][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U]

Comment: how about you count the number of times you have to switch two Elements in order to get same ordering?

Comment: @user99680 About syntax for links in comments, see [How do you cite a reference in a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/how-do-you-cite-a-reference-in-a-comment) or [editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @David When you write *orderings*, do you mean [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)? If it is thecase, the tag ([tag:order-theory]) does not seem suitable for your question. Maybe you can use ([tag:permutations]).

Comment: Good point. Thanks for that! Indeed, I mean permutations.